# Is the Firebase Storage getDownloadURL() re-usable, or should it always be regenerated?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

Is this a good practice to save in the database and reuse the url returned by angularfire2's `getDownloadURL()` rather than executing `getDownloadURL()` every time I need to display an image from Firebase Storage?

If I use `getDownloadURL()` in my component, images are reloaded every time I access the component. I would like to avoid that. If I save the url in my database after the image was uploaded and then use this url every time I need to display the image this solves the problem. However, maybe it's not the right way to do it, and Firebase storage might update the urls at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you should store that `downloadURL` that is generated from the `StorageReference` of the file inside your database structure in that way you are avoiding creating a new file or the same one to get another `downloadURL` , in this case , you can also access this image url from anywhere in your code with `DatabaseReference` and show it anywhere you want.

PS: regenerating the download url implies to reupload the same image and regenerate a new downloadURL, in this case you are wasting networking resources since you are re-doing calls to firebase storage to store the same file, by the way , the file will be replaced but you will be wasting resources. Just upload it once, get the downloadURL, store it in your Database and then retrieve it wherever you would like.

Comment: It seems like `getDownloadURL()` is also used to catch errors and handle authorization checks. See full example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files What makes you think that `getDownloadURL()` replaces the file?

Comment: it does not replace the file, i meant that if you reupload the file and try to get the downloadurl in the success , you will be reuploading the file, but not necesarily you need to upload a file to get the download url , but its a good practice since you can store that url in your database and the nretrieve it wherever you want