# Check if URL exist on Firebase Database before add it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to upload images to **Firebase Storage** and add the download URL using `getDownloadUrl()` method to **Firebase Database**.

I want to check if the URL already exists in **Firebase Database** or not before adding it, I tried to split the URL using `StringUtils.substringBetween(mUrl, "%2F", ".png")`; for example :

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app.appspot.com/o/Frames%2FAPP1565024974054.png

After Splitting I get this which is the name of the file :

**APP1565024974054.png**

So I can check if this string exists in Database or not before adding it.

Here's my code :

**gettingURLs** method: to get all URLs from Database and adding them to ArrayList.

```
private void gettingURLs(String mUrl) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String url = ds.child("url").getValue(String.class);
                    arrayList.add(url);
                }
                verification(arrayList, mUrl);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(createFrame.this, "Ops !,Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**verification** method : to check if URL exists or not

```
   private void verification(ArrayList<String> arrayList, String mUrl) {
        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
            String PREFIX = StringUtils.substringBetween(mUrl, "%2F", ".png");
            for (String str : arrayList) {
                if (str.trim().contains(PREFIX)) {
                    Toast.makeText(createFrame.this, "Frame already uploaded, You don't need to upload it again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Helper.dismissProgressDialog();
                    break;
                } else {
                    addUrlToDataBase(mUrl, mDatabase);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else
            addUrlToDataBase(mUrl, mDatabase);
    }
```

**My issue :**

code above adds all URLs although it already exists in the database, how I can check if URL exist before adding it

1 - If the URL exists, show Toast with

```
Toast.makeText(createFrame.this, "Frame already uploaded, You don't need to upload it again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

2 - If the URL does not exist, Add it normally

Comment: And what's the question? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: @AlexMamo can you please check my update post

Comment: Why are you using `addUrlToDataBase(mUrl, mDatabase);` the second time? I don't think is needed. Does it work without it?

Comment: @AlexMamo if I remove it, how I can add the URL if it's not exists

Comment: Using the first `addUrlToDataBase(mUrl, mDatabase);`, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo the first `addUrlToDataBase(mUrl, mDatabase);` for this case (if URL not exists in Database) the second one is for this case (if Database empty)

Comment: This is a bad way to do it, same user different file but with the same name will turn in an unwanted behaboir. Just allow them to upload and delete if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you upload an image to Firebase storage, you have the option of generating a downloadUrl. **This download url is unique, this means that if you re-upload the same image again, you'll get a different url.** Therefore, comparing downloadUrls is a bad idea as they will never match.

However, there is a way you can manipulate the file name to check whether the file already exists on Firebase storage. Simply create a reference with the file name in it and try to get a download url (before pushing). The response would be null if the file does not exist. Here's a little illustration:

```
void getReferenceAndLoadNewBackground(String photoName) {

    // edit this path to fit your own existing structure
    final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("photos").child(photoName + ".png");

    /* Now, here's where the big deal is.
     * If the image exists, onSuccess would be called.
     * If the image does not exist, onFailure would be called but you'll still need to get the particular error. */
    storageReference.getDownloadUrl()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                // Yaay, the image exists, no need to re-upload.
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // this does not necessarily mean the image does not exist, we still need to check the error code
                int code = ((StorageException) exception).getErrorCode();
                if (code == StorageException.ERROR_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {

                    // haha, the image does not actually exist, upload it
                }
                else {
                    // handle all other problems here
                }

            }
        });
}
```

To learn more about the `getDownloadUrl()` function, you can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50455676/5670752) or read [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files).

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know that the download URL changed but it keeps the same file name, so for that, I compare with the file name, not the URL itself

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the file name before uploading it to FireStorage.

Your Realtime Database structure should be like this:

```
photos: {
   uid:{
          fileName:true
   }
}
```

So before sending the file to storage

```
private void shouldStore(String fileName) {
    rootRef.child("photos").child(uid).child(fileName).addValueEventListenerForSingleEvent(
         // ... if callback returns something dont upload
    )
}
```

Comment: ,thank you so much, I'm a beginner for Firebase Storage, what's RTD? Firebase Storage Rule?

Comment: Ho! Bad assumption on my end. In my example Im using the real time database for checking if the photo was uploades before. So you also have to save the file name there after uploading it to FireStorage